# MVC models converting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to set to a different model?

```
  List<ORDER_DETAILSMetadata> result = db.ORDER_DETAILS.Where(p => p.Order_Number == id).ToList();
```

> Error 6   Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILS>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILSMetadata>`'

ORDER_DETAILSMetadata

```
MetadataType(typeof(ORDER_DETAILSMetadata))]
public partial class ORDER_DETAILS
{
    // Note this class has nothing in it.  It's just here to add the class-level attribute.
}

public class ORDER_DETAILSMetadata
{
    public int Order_Details_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Order_Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Sequence_Number { get; set; }
    public string Item_Num { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Order_Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Ship_Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

ORDER_DETAILS.cs

```
 public partial class ORDER_DETAILS
{
    public int Order_Details_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Order_Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Sequence_Number { get; set; }
    public string Item_Num { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Order_Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Ship_Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide both the models, and what is your expected result?

Comment: The models are the same right now.  I just copied and pasted the ORDER_DETAILS model over to the ORDER_DETAILSMetadata.  But I will be customizing the ORDER_DETAISMetadata later to add more properties like total counts once it works.

Comment: They are not the same models so you would need to modify you query to include `.Select(m => new ORDER_DETAILSMetadata { ID = m.ID, ..... }).ToList();`

Comment: Your `db.ORDER_DETAILS` returns `DbSet<ORDER_DETAILS>`, and your `result` variable is defined as `List<ORDER_DETAILSMetadata>`. Typically, you need the Entity itself, not its meta-data.

Comment: haim, yes I am aware of that, and when I set it equal to the model it works, but I'm customizing the model using ModelMetaData to add properties and other things like counts.

Comment: stephen answer may work, but I do not wan to have to type all that in to set equal.  what if i have 100 fields???  thats bad.  need better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have understood, you can do something like this:

```
List<ORDER_DETAILSMetadata> result = db.ORDER_DETAILS.
                                     Where(p => p.Order_Number == id).
                                     Select(x => new ORDER_DETAILSMetadata 
                                           {
                                              Order_Details_ID = x.Order_Details_ID,
                                              Order_Number = x.Order_Number,
                                              Sequence_Number = x.Sequence_Number,
                                              Item_Num = x.Item_Num,
                                              Order_Quantity = x.Order_Quantity,
                                              Ship_Quantity = x.Ship_Quantity

                                           }).ToList();
```

If you just want to convert one type of model to other type, you can do something like:

```
List<target> targetList = new List<target>(originalList.Cast<target>());
```

You can check the details about Cast() and OfType() [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/07/c.net-little-wonders-use-cast-and-typeof-to-change-sequence.aspx). Go for the first approach when you have different count and types of fields.

Comment: got error when trying this  List<ORDER_DETAILSMetadata> result = new List<ORDER_DETAILSMetadata>(db.ORDER_DETAILS.Where(p => p.Order_Number == id).ToList().Cast<ORDER_DETAILSMetadata>());

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "Unable to cast object of type 'Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILS' to type 'Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILSMetadata'." (System.InvalidCastException)

Comment: This only works if you can cast that type. It always the best option to use first approach. See this link for details:
http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/07/c.net-little-wonders-use-cast-and-typeof-to-change-sequence.aspx